# android get bitmap width and height after scaled by matrix

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap

I use matrix to scale a bitmap and draw it on canvas, after it's scaled, is there a way to get the scale with of the bitmap? and it's scale height?

```
sx += 0.5f;
matrix.setScale(sx, sx);
matrix.postTranslate(left, top);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);

// here how to get the scaled width of bitmap?
```

This is part of my current project - a simple meme maker, so another question is that is there any good tutorials or resource (open source app) I can learn? I googled a lot, just get some pieces no complete tutorials.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe

`Bitmap#getScaledHeight (Canvas canvas)`

should do the job. If not try with

`final int scaledHeight = bitmap.getHeight() * sx;`

but the first one should work.

Comment: thanks, the second one is working, the first one doesn't I guess because canvas belongs to a parent surface view.

Comment: +1 'Bitmap#getScaledHeight(Canvas canvas)' thanks this helped me too in drawing the markers on google maps in android.